# How to verify if column is nullable in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on Oracle SQL Developer, and am relatively new to oracle. I created a package with an "insert into X... select..." Type of query.
The code is as follow:

> Insert into my_table t1 (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) 
>   Select distinct t2.a, t2.b,
>   t2.c  from my_source t2 where ...

Note: the my_table t1 and my_source both have more columns than a, b, and c, but in theory, or at least, in dev environment, they are nullable. I am ONLY interested in those columns for now, but the error is on column "d"

It works in the dev environment no problem, but when run in production the following message happens "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("Schema_name"."table_name"."table_colum_name")".

My theory is that somehow the table column is nullable in the dev environment and not in the production environment.

My issue is that I cannot access directly the production environment tables to verify this, therefore I need to do one of those:

1. Find a way to query the table in prod (most likely using database links) and verify is said column is nullable)
   OR
2. Add a condition for my insert. But I insert column 1-3 and it says column 4 cannot insert null. Therefore I do not think this is doable.

I tried a few queries to check:

- Select Columnproperty(object_id('Schema.table','U'),'column','allowsnull'); But this is for SQL.
- Select is_nullable from sys.colmns where object_id = object_id('schema.table') and name = 'column'; which tells me the table doesn't exist. I am certain of my spelling (in my real code).

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Could you run your select statement only against production? Just to confirm that it doesn't have a null value where you didn't see the same output in development. Secondly, is your development environment a copy/backup of the production environment? If nothing else, you should be able to request a backup be restored to development by the DBA who manages your production instance.

Comment: The select statement works as expected in prod (tested using db links). In theory the environment is a copy of production, but it must not be the case. Which is what I want to verify (by checking if the column is nullable in prod) before escalading the issue. Any advice on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Can you try this, let's check for default value. Should be null for a nullable field, i would think.
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
select nullable
  from all_tab_columns
 where owner = '<<schema owner>>'
   and table_name = '<<table name>>'
   and column_name = '<<column name>>'
```

Note that

- In 99% of cases, `owner`, `table_name`, and `column_name` should all be upper case in the data dictionary.  You can have case sensitive identifiers in Oracle, it is just rare.
- In Oracle, there is a pattern for data dictionary tables that there are `user_`, `all_` and `dba_` variants.  So there is a `user_tab_columns` that shows information about all the columns of tables you own, a `dba_tab_columns` that shows information about all the columns of all the tables in the database, and an `all_tab_columns` that shows information about all the columns of all the tables that you have access to.  Depending on the permissions you have and the owner of the table, you may be able to use the `dba_` or `user_` version of the data dictionary table instead of `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: Here's a couple strange concepts: 1. Believe the DBMS. If you get a NULL constraint violation then the column is defined as NOT NULL.  2. Ask the DBA to verify and correct the environment that's wrong.